# Is it possible to get the time of executing my script and then use it in my script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script which counts my SQL backup files (.bak) in a folder. I just want to check if the amount of files is correct. For this reason I only need the files which are newly created.

```
$backupfolder = "C:\backup\"

(Get-Childitem -filter *.bak $backupfolder).Count | Where-Object ({ $_.lastwritetime.minutes -lt 20 })
```

This one is working fine, but IF I have to run this backup again because the amount was not ok, the amount of files in the last 20minutes changes. so I want to have a solution which does this :

Take time when i execute script and then count the amount of .bak files which are created AFTER executing my script.

I  tried to use "get-date" but I didn't manage to use the output as variable.
When I use `$Scriptstartingtime = "get-date"`  it will only save the text `"get-date"`

Is there a way? thanks in advance!

```
time modified > script started...
```

Comment: remove the quotes (") for your call to Get-Date: $x = get-date

Comment: hehe thanks i just figured out.  now i try to use it like this : Where-Object ({ $_.lastwritetime -gt "$Scriptstartingtime" })  i gues :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

Declare a variable at the start time:

```
$Now = get-date
```

This is a PowerShell object, so you do not need to worry about formatting, or how it reads.

Then, to see what is newer then when the variable was created:

```
ls | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Now} | select Name
```

Of course, you can adjust what happens with the found items, but there are the basics of it.